# regex How to match duplicate attribute names inside a single element (<>)

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to search for elements with duplicate style or class attributes.  I can only get matching lines but I'd like more defined matching to the actual element (inside the <>).  Anyone have an example?  Below is some HTML and a search should only match the top div because it has two style attributes.

```
<div style="width:100%;" style="height:100%;">
<div class="thisclass">Inner DIV</div>
<span class="thisstyle">Test Code</span>
</div>
```

I can get all lines that have duplicate attributes by using `<.+(class)=("|').+?\2.+?\1.+>` but that gives some false positives if there are multiple brackets/elements on the line.

Comment: Use `[^>]` instead of `.` to match any character except `>`, so it won't go past the end of an element.

Comment: BTW, this is finally an example where it **is** appropriate to use a regexp to parse HTML, since a DOM parser would ignore the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated.

The following solution is universal - it will give you any duplicate attributes within the tag. I've tested that thoroughly:

```
<[a-z]++\s++([a-z][-a-z_\d]++(?:\s*+=\s*+(?:(["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\2).)*+\2|[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]++))?+[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]++)*?(([a-z][-a-z_\d]++)(?:\s*+=\s*+(?:(["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\5).)*+\5|[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]++))?+[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]++)*([a-z][-a-z_\d]++(?:\s*+=\s*+(?:(["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\7).)*\7|[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]++))?+[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]++)*?(\4\b(?:\s*+=\s*+(?:(["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\9).)*+\9|[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]++))?+[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]*+)[^>]*>
```

(Use **case insensitive** mode for this regex)

It will make you sure, that you **correctly capture cases** like:

1. `<div style = "font-family:\"Open Sans\"" style= "font-size:2em">`
2. `<div class='one' width=20 class>`
3. `<div style="color:white" style=color:black!important>`

Capturing groups **$3** and **$8** give you the 1st and 2nd occurence of your attributes with its values.

### [Take a look at it visually and interactively here](https://regex101.com/r/M0XbwA/10).

[image: Check regular expression online visually and interactively]

**P.S.:**
The below explains the usage of `[\w{@#():,*!!\[\]}]` in regular expression:

> `<div rel={@#():,*!![[]]}></div>`: this looks weird, but none of these characters are problematic and no browser has any problem with that.

I also added dash "-" to the list of characted, that can be interpreted as attribute value and will not break it, as modern browsers behave in this way.

Comment: This expression is intense!  Thanks for the explanation and link to regex playground.  However, it did not work for me in Visual Studio.  I didn't include that in my question and your expression helped me understand how to build the expression that was useful for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @jp77 , I've updated the regex and tested it thogourhly. it should now work for you also.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent going past the end of an element, use `[^>]+` instead of `.+`. `[^>]` matches any character other than `>`.

```
<[^>]+(class)=["'][^>]+?\2[^>]+?\1[^>]+>
```

Comment: This matches lines that have more than one element.  It did help me understand the expression though.

Comment: I missed one of the `.`. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

for example you can use `\sclass\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"[\s\>]` in group one you will find all the class names of an attribute. Simply split on whitespace and check if all values are unique.

The problem is writing a regex that always works. Since a regex is not an html interpreter something can always go wrong: Say a page has javascript and inside there i do something weird and somehow the regex matches `var class = "test test" ;` no my regex fires but its not a html class attribute.

You would be better of finding a library that can properly interpret html and periodically (because it might be way slower) check if html contains double classes names.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion for using an interpreter.  However, this should be a reasonable search for regex also.  I'm not worried about edge cases or every variation.  Your expression is also matching lines with multiple elements which have a only a single attribute.  It helped me find a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

(I do not have enough reputation to post a comment yet.)

I have modified [@NikitOn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140973/13723591) to replace the possessive quantifiers with atomic groups, since possessive quantifiers are not supported by the regex engine in Visual Studio 2017.

```
<(?>[a-z]+)\s+([a-z](?>[-a-z_\d]+)(?>(?:(?>\s*)=(?>\s*)(?:(["'])(?>(?:(?!(?<!\\)\2).)*)\2|(?>[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]+)))?)(?>[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]+))*?(([a-z](?>[-a-z_\d]+))(?>(?:(?>\s*)=(?>\s*)(?:(["'])(?>(?:(?!(?<!\\)\5).)*)\5|(?>[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]+)))?)(?>[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]+))*([a-z](?>[-a-z_\d]+)(?>(?:(?>\s*)=(?>\s*)(?:(["'])(?:(?!(?<!\\)\7).)*\7|(?>[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]+)))?)(?>[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]+))*?(\4\b(?>(?:(?>\s*)=(?>\s*)(?:(["'])(?>(?:(?!(?<!\\)\9).)*)\9|(?>[-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}]+)))?)(?>[^-a-z_\d{@#():,*!!\[\]}>]*))[^>]*>
```